# Python 3 subprocess crash

Tags: python, crash, subprocess

I have a problem with subprocess.Popen, subprocess.call or subprocess.run.
If I try to run following skript:

```
cmd = "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Phoenix Contact Software/TPS Configurator/FS_PROG/FS_PROG.exe\""
arg1 = " \"tps_configurator.xml\""
arg2 = " 192.168.16.227"
arg3 = " 192.168.16.29"
arg4 = ' {0:0{1}X} '.format(intmac,12)
arg5 = ' {0:0{1}X} '.format(intmac + 1,12)
arg6 = ' {0:0{1}X} '.format(intmac + 2,12)
arg7 = " \"0               \""

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd + arg1 + arg2 + arg3 + arg4 + arg5 + arg6 + arg7)
time.sleep(5)
input("\npress enter to quit")
```

Python crashes and the powershell, where I started the script, closes immediately.
If I remove time.sleep(5) it works.
With p.wait() I have the same issue.
If the script waits for the programm it comes to the crash.
I also tryed os.system, subprocess.run and subprocess.call with the same results.
I tryed it with Python 3.9.5 and Python 3.10.

Comment: I suggest that you construct the string outside of the call to Popen and print it. Then, copy that and paste it into your CMD window to see what happens. You may also want to review Popen usage here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: @BrutusForcus That was the first thing I tryed and the printed output worked in the CMD.